# Solution to matrix equation $A = X B X^\top$ with positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Suppose $A$ is a positive definite $m \times m$ matrix, and $B$ is a positive definite $n \times n$ matrix; note that $m$ and $n$ are not necessarily equal. Is there a closed-form solution to the equation $A = X B X^\top$? If there are multiple solutions, then I'm fine with any closed-form solution. If there is no closed-form solution, then is there a standard way of numerically solving such an equation, besides just minimizing $\min ||A-X B X^\top||^2$ with (say) gradient descent?

If $m = n$, this problem has closed-form solution $X =A^{-1/2} (A^{1/2} B A^{1/2} )^{1/2}A^{-1/2}$, but I don't know how to generalize to when $m \ne n$.

Comment: Just a remark. From the equation, we must have $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. If $m >n$, we have $m^2$ equations with $m\cdot n$ variables $X_{ij}$, then there are  infinitely many solutions. For the case $m<n$, the number of equations is less than the number of variables ($m^2 < m\cdot n$), it is very likely that there is no solution.

Comment: The rank of $X B X^T$   is no larger than the rank of $B.$  But $A$  is full rank because it is symmetric definite.  So your equation has no solutions when $m >n$

Comment: In my first comment, please switch the conclusion of the two mentionned cases.

Comment: For a solution (not unique), just consider block diagonal $B'$ with $B$ on the leading block, then $I_{n-m}$ on the other block.   Then use you formula for the equal dimensions case, and at the end delete irrelevant rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your problem to be solvable you need of course $n\geq m$, otherwise the rank of the two sides cannot match, so I first take that as an assumption. Since $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, we can express them through their eigenvalue decompositions as
\begin{equation}
A = U_A \Lambda_A U_A^\mathrm{T},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B = U_B \Lambda_B U_B^\mathrm{T},
\end{equation}
where $U_A$ and $U_B$ are orthogonal matrices (i.e., $U_A\cdot U_A^\mathrm{T}=I_m$, and the same goes for $B$ after adapting dimensions), while $\Lambda_A$ and $\Lambda_B$ are diagonal matrices with the positive eigenvalues in the diagonal. We can then construct the solution simply by
\begin{equation}
X = U_A \begin{bmatrix}\Lambda_A^{1/2} & 0_{m\times (n-m)}\end{bmatrix} \Lambda_B^{-1/2} U_B^T.
\end{equation}
The intuition is that $X$ and $X^\mathrm{T}$ are first diagonalizing $B$, then compensating its eigevalues to $1$, and then fixing $A$. Of course the lower $(n-m)$ rows of $\Lambda_B^{-1/2} U_B^T$ don't affect your solution, so you can take this into account if you want to be more efficient there.

Answer (score 1):

An $\ m\times n\ $ matrix $\ X\ $ satisfies the equation
$$
A=XBX^T\tag{1}\label{e1}
$$
if and only if
$$
X=\sqrt{A}\,U\sqrt{B}^{-1}\tag{2}\label{e2}\ ,
$$
where $\ \sqrt{A}, \sqrt{B}\ $ are symmetric square roots of $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ ,$ respectively, and $\ U\ $ is an $\ m\times n\ $ matrix with orthonormal rows. As Juan notes in his answer this is possible if and only if $\ m\ge n\ $

Suppose $\ X\ $ satisfies equation (\ref{e2}). Then
\begin{align}
XBX^T&=X\sqrt{B}^2X^T\\
&=\big(\sqrt{A}\,U\sqrt{B}^{-1}\big)\sqrt{B}^2\big(\sqrt{A}\,U\sqrt{B}^{-1}\big)^T\\
&=\sqrt{A}\,U\sqrt{B}^{-1}\sqrt{B}^2\sqrt{B}^{-1}U^T\sqrt{A}\\
&=A
\end{align}
by the symmetry of $\ \sqrt{A}\ $ and $\ \sqrt{B}\ $ and the orthonormality of the rows of $\ U\ .$

Now suppose $\ X\ $ is a solution of equation (\ref{e1}) and let $\ \sqrt{A}, \sqrt{B}\ $ be any symmetric square roots of $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ ,$ respectively.  Then,multiplying the equation
\begin{align}
A&=XBX^T\\
&=X\sqrt{B}^2X^T\\
&=\big(X\sqrt{B}\big)\big(X\sqrt{B}\big)^T
\end{align}
on the left and right by $\ \sqrt{A}^{-1}\ $ gives
\begin{align}
I_{m\times m}&=\sqrt{A}^{-1}\big(X\sqrt{B}\big)\big(X\sqrt{B}\big)^T\sqrt{A}^{-1}\\
&=\big(\sqrt{A}^{-1}X\sqrt{B}\big)\big(\sqrt{A}^{-1}X\sqrt{B}\big)^T\\
&=UU^T\ . \tag{3}\label{e3}
\end{align}
where $\ U\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sqrt{A}^{-1}X\sqrt{B}\ .$ It follows from equation (\ref{e3}) that the rows of $\ U\ $ are orthonormal, and from the definition of $\ U\ $ that
$$
X=\sqrt{A}\,U\sqrt{B}^{-1}\ .
$$
Therefore $\ X\ $ has the form given by equation (\ref{e2}).